# Closing the entire site collection except a couple of lists using Site Policies

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, administration

I am trying to close a site collection in SharePoint 2013, however, I need to have a couple of lists in one of the subsites open

Is this possible using Site Policies?

Or what would be the best approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to achieve your requirement when using site policies.

When you set a site policy in site collection, it will close the entire site collection.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-policies-for-site-closure-and-deletion-a8280d82-27fd-48c5-9adf-8a5431208ba5